# Does only the .github/workflows folder in the master branch matter?

Tags: github-actions

Let's say I want a workflow to run every time a pull request is created. Will GitHub Actions look for the `.github/workflows` folder in the master branch, in the destination branch for the PR, or in the source branch for the PR?

Is the master branch the only one that matters for GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does only the .github/workflows folder in the master branch matter?

No, GitHub Actions will use workflows from the `GITHUB_SHA` associated with the event type. In many cases that will be master because the `GITHUB_SHA` associated with some event types is the "last commit on default branch."

If you take a look at the documentation at the link below you can see that every event type describes what `GITHUB_SHA` means in that context.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/events-that-trigger-workflows

For `pull_request` events you can see that `GITHUB_SHA` is described as follows.

> Last merge commit on the GITHUB_REF branch

And the `GITHUB_REF` branch is described as follows.

> PR merge branch refs/pull/:prNumber/merge

So when you create a pull request GitHub Actions will look for `on: pull_request` workflows in the last commit of the source branch. You can verify this with the following test.

1. Commit an `on: pull_request` workflow to master
2. Create a feature branch and delete the workflow
3. Raise a pull request from the feature branch to master
4. Verify that the `on: pull_request` workflow does not execute

Comment: I see! So it's actually the source branch of the PR, meaning one would better create the workflow files before branching if he wants uniform behavior on all of the branches.

Comment: @memememe bingo, optimally the workflow is defined and doesn't really change before any real development starts